# Accessing a nested dictionary unordered_map<string, void*> in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, void-pointers, unordered-map

Suppose we are provided a nested dictionary in which that values are either a string or another dictionary, which is declared as:

`unordered_map<string, void*> dictionary`

How can we access and perform operations using this dictionary?

Comment: how will you know whether the `void*` points to a string or dictionary? or is that the root of the question?

Comment: turn that `void*` into a custom type that holds a string or another dictionary and you can query which it has.

Comment: This information is given to us  in the question.

Comment: Look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/ or http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/. But why dont you use ``map``, which should be readable faster by binary search (writing to ``map`` is slower than writing to ``unordered_map`` because ``map`` seeks for a good place to insert the new value and ``unordered_dict`` just appends it but needs more time to read).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a [variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) type instead of a `void*` pointer.

So declare the unordered map like this

```
struct Map {
    std::unordered_map<
        std::string, 
        std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Map>, std::string>
    > mp;
};
```

And then use it like this

```
auto map = Map{};
// insert another map for the key "something"
map.mp["something"] = std::make_unique<Map>();
// insert a string for the key "else"
map.mp["else"] = "whatever";
```

And then use the map like this (with C++17) where `operator<<` is overloaded for the `Map` type

```
// gotta love structured bindings <3
for (const auto& [key, value] : map) {
    std::visit(value, [&key](auto& value) { 
        cout << key << " : " << value << endl;
    }
}
```

Or with C++14

```
for (const auto& key_value : map) {
    std::visit(value, [&key_value](auto& value) {
        cout << key_value.first << " : " << value << endl;
    }
}
```

If you do not have access to C++17 then you can still use independent implementations of variant such as `boost::variant`, etc.  The logic and code will look surprisingly similar

---

If you are given a pointer to `void*` for some reason, and you **absolutely cannot change the API**, you can use the following minimally viable solution

```
struct StringOrAnother {
    enum class Type { STRING, MAP };
    Type type;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, void*> mp;
    std::string str;
};

auto mp = std::unordered_map<std::string, void*> mp;

// insert a string
auto val_one = new StringOrAnother{STRING};
val_one.str = "some value";
mp["key one"] = &val_one;
auto val_two = new StringOrAnother{MAP};
mp["key two"] = &val_two;

void print(const std::unordered_map<std::string, void*>& mp) {

    for (const auto& key_value : mp) {
        cout << key_value.first << " : ";
        auto& value = *static_cast<StringOrAnother*>(&key_value.second);
        if (value.second.type == StringOrAnother::STRING) {
            cout << value.second.str << endl;
        } else {
            print(value.second.mp);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I have not used `unique_ptr` for the pointers and have allocated them manually.  It is up to you to `delete` them later on and not leak memory!

Comment: `any` is also a good idea (for type-safe access).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Comment: Should probably add that `std::variant` is part of C++17 (and OP's question is about C++11)

Comment: @UnholySheep There's also boost::variant and boost::any, or independent versions for it.

Comment: If you know that it is one of two types, `any` seems pretty heavy-handed.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I don't think `any` is a good idea for this situation.  If the list of types is known at compile time, then `std::variant` is a lot more efficient

Comment: @Curious, Thank you very much. But, I have already given to use " void* " .

Comment: @BishalGautam If you are stuck with `void*`, well so be it, but know that in real world C++ the only time you should be using a `void*` is if you are interfacing with another library that demands you provide a `void*`. Using a `void*` within a C++ program is a sign of a bad design. Avoid it like the plague.

Comment: @user4581301 is very right, avoid `void*` as much as possible

Comment: @BishalGautam if the answer was acceptable to you don't forget to mark it as accepted!  There should be a tick mark right near where you upvote the question that you should be able to click